# Remove edges by specifying endpoints

Tags: r, igraph

How can I delete edges from a graph by naming their endpoints?

`delete_edges` expects edge numbers, and it's not clear to me the mapping between endpoints and edge numbers.

```
library(igraph)
g = make_ring(10)
```

Say I wanted to remove the vertices between nodes 7&8 and nodes 9&10.

A hackish way to do so is:

```
g = delete_edges(g, c(7, 9))
```

But I had to inspect the output of `E(g)` closely before figuring out that those edges are numbered 7 & 9.

I tried looking for how the `print` methods assign the node mapping to `E(g)` but it looks like quite the rabbit hole.

Comment: @GaborCsardi not sure why you deleted your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can do this with a string argument -- see the second example in `?delete_edges`.

```
g = delete_edges(g, c("7|8", "9|10"))
g
# IGRAPH U--- 10 8 -- Ring graph
# + attr: name (g/c), mutual (g/l), circular (g/l)
# + edges:
# [1] 1-- 2 2-- 3 3-- 4 4-- 5 5-- 6 6-- 7 8-- 9 1--10
```

Apparently `c("7|8", "9|10")` also counts as an "edge sequence" as described in the `edges` argument.

Comment: Hmm thanks. Somehow missed that in `?delete_edges`. And the way `igraph:::print.igraph.es` works remains a mystery to me. Kind of a pain that `add_edges` and `delete_edges` don't have parallel interface...

Comment: What is a parallel interface?

Comment: like the same style of input works for both adding and subtracting. you deleted your answer; I was going to ask if there's a corresponding `+` method?

Answer (score 0):

Nota that:

```
get.edge.ids(g, c(7,8, 9, 10))
```

will return edge ids 7, 9. Therefore

```
delete_edges(g, get.edge.ids(g, c(7,8, 9, 10)))
```

produces the desired result:

```
1] 1-- 2 2-- 3 3-- 4 4-- 5 5-- 6 6-- 7 8-- 9 1--10
```